# Update array state from out of a for each loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state of an array from out of a forEach loop without loosing the previous state. I`m trying to archive something like the following:

```
const initialState = [{question: "a", answer: ""}, {question: "b", answer: ""}]
const [request, setRequests] = useState(initialState);

const run = () => {
    request.forEach((request, idx) => {
        fetch("/ask").then(data => data.json()).then(response => {
            let currentState = request;
            request[idx] = Object.assign(...request[idx], {answer: response.answer});
            setRequests(currentState);
        })
    })
}
```

But in such a case only one response will be rendered. Any idea how to archive something like this?

Comment: So, you want to set the `answer` property within the object, which is at position `idx`?

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problems

There are a couple of issues there:

- You're breaking one of the fundamental rules of React state: [Do not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). Doing `const currentState = request;` doesn't copy the object, it just makes two variables point to the same object.
- You're using the version of state setter where you just pass in the update, which completely overwrites any previous outstanding state updates.

#### Solutions

There are (at least) two approaches here:

1. Do piecemeal updates as you are in that code, where earlier updates are stored in state (causing a re-render) while later updates are still in progress

   or
2. Get all the updated information, and do a single state update (and render)

Both are valid depending on your use case.

##### Piecemeal Updates

For the piecemeal updates, since you're doing a bunch of state updates (which may not occur in order, depending on the vagaries of the timing of the `fetch` replies). Since you're updating state based on previous state (the other entries in the array), you need to use the callback version of the state setter. Then, you need to create a new array each time, and and new object within the array for the object at index `idx`, like this:

```
// *** Note I've renamed `request` to `requests` -- it's an array, it should
// use the plural, and you use `request` for an individual one later.
// I've also reversed `response` and `data`, since they were backward in the
// original. I've also added (minimal) handling of errors.
const [requests, setRequests] = useState(initialState);
const run = () => {
    requests.forEach((request, idx) => {
        // (It seems odd that nothing from `request` is used in the `fetch`)
        fetch("/ask")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setRequests((prevRequests) =>
                    prevRequests.map((request, index) => {
                        return idx === index ? { ...request, answer: data.answer } : request;
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // ...handle/report error...
            });
    });
};
```

`map` creates the new array, returning a new object for the one at index `idx`, or the previous unchanged ones for the others.

##### All At Once

The other approach is to do all the `fetch` calls, wait for them all to complete, and then do a single state update, like this:

```
// (Same naming and error-handling updates)
const run = () => {
    Promise.all(requests.map((request) =>
        fetch("/ask")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            return {...request, answer: data.answer};
        })
    ))
    .then(setRequests)
    .catch((error) => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the new array at once and update it, something like this

```
const run = () => {
    Promise.all(request.map((r) => fetch("/ask").then(data => data.json())))
        .then((responses) => {
            const newRequest = responses.map(res => ({answer: res.answer}))
            setRequests(newRequest);
        })
}
```

Using Promise.all allows you to retrieve all the json response at once, so you can build the new state in one shot.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

note: code not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You problem stems from the fact that `let currentState = request` will keep a reference to the `request` at the time of making the `closure`. This means that it won't get updated by future calls.

You need to use the `functional` version of `setState`. Something like this:

```
const initialState = [{question: "a", answer: ""}, {question: "b", answer: ""}]
const [request, setRequests] = useState(initialState);

const run = () => {
    request.forEach((request, idx) => {
        fetch("/ask").then(data => data.json()).then(response => {
            setRequests(currentState => {
              currentState[request[idx]] = {answer: response.answer};
              return {...currentState};
            });
        })
    })
}
```